# is it possible for a battry to provide to many watts to a dc motor

Tags: motor

is it possible for a battry to provide to many watts to a dc electric motor. the motor is 36v 250w internal resistance is unknown, the battery is 3-12v 10a sla battries connected in series

Comment: Please use proper English capitalization and spelling.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean **too** many watts, if the motor is rated at 36V it will be okay if the load is not too high.

Just about any normal DC motor will overheat and may be destroyed if you load the shaft too heavily or completely stall the motor.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. But SLAs won't last very long if you sustain the high power. Try using NiCad or Li-ion batteries instead, paralleling them if longer runtime is required; they are better suited to sustained high currents.

250W / 36V = 6.95A